# Why do strings behave like an array in PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, arrays, string, php-5.3, php-5.4

I have this code:

```
$tierHosts['host'] = isset($host['name']) ? $host['name'] : $host;
```

It's working fine in PHP 5.5, but in PHP 5.3 the condition returns true while `$host` contains a string like `pjba01`. It returns the first letter of `$tierHosts['host']`, that is, `p`.

What's so wrong with my code?

Comment: You can bypass this behaviour with `(is_array($host) && isset($host["name"]))`. Always check against the type you need if it's not clear which type you'll received. For more details on the behaviour you described see Rizier123s answer.

Comment: If you are interested in some of the other things that can catch you off-guard in PHP, read this. http://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/

Comment: Why do strings behave like an array...? Because they are an array...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[You can access strings like an array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr) and prior PHP 5.4 offsets like your `name` were silently casted to 0, means you accessed the first character of that string:

```
character | p | j | b | a | 0 | 1 |
-----------------------------------
index     | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
```

After 5.3 such offsets will throw a notice, as you can also read in the manual:

> As of PHP 5.4 string offsets have to either be integers or integer-like strings, otherwise a warning will be thrown. Previously an offset like "foo" was silently cast to 0.